# Unavailable languages in REPORT_LOCALE in jasper report

Tags: java, internationalization, jasper-reports

I try to create jasper report (Internationalized reports) in different languages. `REPORT_LOCALE` parameter used to specify the runtime locale when filling the report. but some languages not available in the jasper report designer.
how to create properties file for new languages based on `REPORT_LOCALE`. is it possible.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your response @AlexK  . this  works for me.  'Locale locale = new Locale("sin", "LK");'

Answer (score 1):

REPORT_LOCALE Configuration uses **java.util.locale**

Since the locale you mentioned is not directly supported http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html#installers

Try using the Icu Library, for getting the locale.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sample Code below.

```
ULocale locale = ULocale.forLanguageTag("si-LK");
Locale java = locale.toLocale();
```

Comment: i try to use "Sinhalese"

Comment: @resatz What is a reason to use external library for this basic task? `java.util.Locale` class has several constructors for instantiation

Comment: @resatz thank you. i try with AlexK answer. it works for me.

Comment: if the solution works, please upvote :-) Thanks!